# Fix some controls inside when UserControl has scroll

Tags: asp.net, user-controls, webforms

I need to prevent scrolling entire UserControl. Instead I need to fix TextBox and Button at top but scroll GridView. Now it's scrolling entire user control.

Comment: COMMENT reason when downvoting!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your Grid View inside an asp:panel like this and keep the rest out of it :

```
 <asp:Panel ScrollBars="Vertical" runat="server" ID="pnlGrid">
         <asp:GridView runat="server" ID="Grid1"></asp:GridView>


     </asp:Panel>
```

Regards

and Seriously Guys give the users reason while down-voting